# Не работает auto_increment

Tags: sql-server

Студия выдает ошибку `Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "auto_increment".` Что тут не так

```
create table Categories(id int not null primary key auto_increment ,CategoryName nvarchar(20) unique,Description nvarchar(50))
```

Comment: Согласно документации https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html primary key пишется после auto_increment

Comment: @Mike понял местами, все равно не работает

Comment: А у вас СУБД какая ?

Comment: В MySQL отлично создается http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d65ae3/1

Comment: @Mile ms sql 2014

Comment: А в ms sql нет auto_increment, там похожая вещь называется IDENTITY. Смотрите документацию на свою СУБД

Comment: IDENTITY(1,1) добавьте, если увеличивать на 1 нужно

Comment: @Mike благодарю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Categories (
  id int IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  CategoryName nvarchar(20) UNIQUE,
  Description nvarchar(50)
)
```

Подробнее: [CREATE TABLE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

```
create table Categories
(
  id int not null IDENTITY(1,1) primary key,
  CategoryName nvarchar(20) unique,
  Description nvarchar(50)
)
```

Comment: не совсем то что хотел автор вопроса, ваш скрипт не создаст индекс и констрейнт на уникальность поля [Id].

Comment: @NickProskuryakov, хм.. Если так, то надо добавить `primary key` к `identity`.